# My r.java file is not generated

Tags: android, console, shared-libraries, google-play-services, libgcc

I get this error from the console:

```
[2016-01-02 19:11:15 - google-play-services_lib] /home/fibrahim/Unduhan/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And,

```
[2016-01-02 19:11:15 - SpeciesGallery] /home/fibrahim/Unduhan/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: People edit posts on [so] doesn't mean that they know the answer. We edit posts to let them be more clear and answerable. Please check the question [How does editing work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem, following :

[shared library problems with eclipse on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588471/shared-library-problems-with-eclipse-on-ubuntu)

I execute this command :
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib